# In Azure data studio I am unable to find add foreign key or any other constraint option

Tags: constraints, ssms, azure-data-studio

I'm using ubuntu and to Azure Data Studio tool for DB connection. I'm able to apply key constraint using Sequelize ORM but for sample test table I want to create key constraints manually without running query,  *Is there any GUI option azure data studio to achieve the same?*
Is there a GUI option for exporting SQL schema with data as well?